# Вопрос по функции split

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать, если в шаблоне слово парное, например "Как дела".
Пример ниже в коде с функцией split работает только для единичного слова. Например, говорю - "Как дела дружище". Хотелось что бы программа принимала ввод, основываясь на шаблоне "Как дела". С помощью split уже вроде никак не реализовать? Буду благодарен за совет. Спасибо.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import random

mic = sr.Microphone(device_index=2)

ansver_list = ['здравствуйте', 'приветствую', 'привет', 'рад вас слышать']

def speek(words):
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
    engine.setProperty('voice', voices[3].id)
    engine.say(words)
    engine.runAndWait()

def command():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with mic as source:
        audio = r.listen(source=mic)
    try:
        query = r.recognize_google(audio_data=audio, language='ru-RU').lower()
    except:
        query = command()
    return query


hello = ['привет', 'здравствуй', 'приветствую']

def talking(query):

    if query.split()[0].lower() in hello:
        print(speek(words=random.choice(ansver_list)))
    else:
        print(speek(words='я не понял ваш запрос'))

while True:
    talking(command())
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136122/discussion-on-question-by-----split).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. В частности спасибо Сергею Шашко.

Вот так работает:

```
    def talking(query):
        for tr in hello:
            if query.find(tr) >=0:
              print(speek(words=random.choice(ansver_list)))   
              return
        else:
              print(speek(words='я не понял ваш запрос'))

while True:
    talking(command())
```

Comment: а я и забыл что у for есть else. Спасибо что напомнили.

Comment: вот, век живи век учись)))) друг у друга)))

Answer (score 0):

```
def talking(query):
    query = query.lower()
    temp = True
    for x in hello:
       if query.find(x) >=0:
           print(query)
           temp = False
           break
    if temp:
        print('я не понял ваш запрос')

hello =['здравствуйте', 'приветствую', 'привет', 'рад вас слышать']
query = 'рад вас слышать'
talking(query)

рад вас слышать
```

Comment: не работает, сразу завершается

Comment: это идеально  if query.find('привет друг') >=0:  а если уже список теребить то что то блин не получается

Comment: обновил ответ, проверил, работает алгоритм, адаптируйте под ваши нужды.

Comment: Да мне без разницы от куда. Лень импортами заниматься. Чисто для проверки что функция работает как задумана. Адаптируйте под ваши нужды.

Comment: хорошо. спасибо за ответы. да конструкция, указанная вами, как таковая работает. но не так как нужно. В коде выше, из моего вопроса, она не работает. Даже с адаптацией под код. буду изучать дальше)))

Comment: Я в телеграм https://t.me/Bum_Bok